# Collect user input to determine size of rectangle in Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

We were asked to create a function `draw_rectangle()` with 4 parameters that when called forms a rectangle. I tried writing a code but when I run it, an error comes up for the 'turtle.goto(x,y)' saying its a string or something, here is the code:

```
import turtle 

def draw_rectangle(x, y, width, height):
  turtle.up()
  turtle.goto(x, y)
  turtle.down()
  turtle.forward(width)          
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(height)
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(width)
  turtle.left(90)
  turtle.forward(height)
  turtle.left(90)


x = print(input("Enter x"))
y = print(input("Enter y"))
width = print(input("Enter width"))
height = print(input("Enter height"))
print(draw_rectangle(x, y, width, height))
```

Comment: I think all the variables you have assigned will be `None`, since you assign them the value returned by `print`. Remove the `print`s and cast the input values to `int` (as answered already)

Comment: What's the exact error? Can you print the values of `x` and `y` before you use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input is a string; you have to convert it to numeric.  Also, you seem to be a little confused in your input/output sequence.

```
x = int(input("Enter x"))
y = int(input("Enter y"))
```

Do likewise with width & height.  This isn't hardy: if someone enters a bad value, the program will crash, but that's likely not a problem for you at the moment.

Comment: it still doesn't work though, it keeps saying its a string type even after I did what you said.

Comment: Can you please update your source code *and* paste in the error message?  Sometimes there is an extra bit of info in the exact message.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question but you could use:

```
    for side in range(2)
         turtle.forward(100)
         turtle.right(90)
         turtle.forward(50)
         turtle.right(90)
```

and also if you do:

```
    from turtle import *
```

you won't have to write

```
    turtle.forward()
```

just

```
    forward()
```